# add a no results message to table filteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this following code which does filter a table but when there is no result it is blank.

Could someone help me out here to add a "No results found" message show when nothing found?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table_search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    
    $("#filter tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="filter"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly note that your use of `filter()` isn't quite correct. It's intended to be used to reduce a set of elements based on a predicate condition supplied within the function argument which returns a boolean. Instead your current logic is using it as a basic looping mechanism.

With regard to the issue, you can use `filter()` to find matching rows by their text, then based on the number of filtered rows, hide or display the 'No matches' message. Something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $rows = $('#filter tr');
  let $tfoot = $('tfoot');

  $("#table_search").on("input", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();    
    if (!value) {
      $rows.show();
      $tfoot.hide()
      return;
    }
    
    let $filteredRows = $rows.filter((i, el) => el.innerText.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1);    
    if ($filteredRows.length) {
      $tfoot.hide();
      $rows.hide();
      $filteredRows.show()
    } else {
      $rows.hide();
      $tfoot.show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
tfoot { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="table_search" />
<table>
  <tbody id="filter">
    <tr><td>Lorem</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ipsum</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dolor</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sit</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Amet</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Consectetur</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Adipiscing</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Elit</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>No matches</td></tr>   
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Finally, note the use of `input` instead of `keyup`. The latter works better in this instance as it also works for users who copy/paste text in to the search box.